# Change HTML code without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, frontend

Is there any possibility `how to change HTML` (.jsp) page `without refreshing` it?

Usecase is that user writes something to textarea then hits some button and I need then to add some object ie picture to previously defined place in my page ~~~> I need to change HTML code without refreshing the page (without the loss of the text in the textbox). I really need to change the HTML code, so pls don't advice any solution without changing the HTML code.

I'm not very into frontend technologies, so I don't know if it's even possible, so excuse me pls, if this is a stupid question.

I can use only frontend technologies.

Comment: This is so general that it describes a great deal of the JavaScript from the last ~10 years. I suggest you take a look at JQuery - it will probably help with what you need.

Comment: oh..thanks...as I've said - I usually write backend in java, so I don't have a clue, what frontend technologies provide and what are the possibilities. I'll check this out :)

Comment: Look into javascript [event handlers](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript) and dynamic DOM element creation / CSS display attribute.

Comment: Honestly, I'm voting this up. Yes it's vague, but I think there would be many frontend-beginners out there who would search these exact words when trying to accomplish something like this. This is a great opportunity to help point future beginner visitors in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `jQuery` (a JavaScript library) you can utilize the `load()` function to load the contents of another HTML file on your server and place it anywhere you want on the current page without refreshing (so you can even replace the current HTML if you like).

**jQuery:**
http://jquery.com/

**jQuery load():**
http://api.jquery.com/load/

---

**Alternative Suggestion:**
However, I know you say you can't refresh the page, **but**, if the only reason is because you need to keep the text in the textbox, you could use a form to `POST` that text to another `.jsp` page (or even the same `.jsp` page, depending on how you go about it) where it will be available to you to use at your own discretion (to put it in another textbox, for example).

Comment: nah..your alternative solution would be too much complicated...I just need to add new tab to some tabcomponent, when user wan't it.. And I don't want only because of this send all informations about text in forms etc. to controller on the server, and return it back to the same view, only updated.. it's like scratching with left hand on the right ear.. :)

Comment: @Dworza Haha ok! Well jQuery is a fantastic library, I hope it helps you out. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<a id="refresh">click</a>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function() {
     $("#mydiv").load("yourdomain.com/file.php")
  })
})
```

also see this:

http://woork.blogspot.nl/2007/10/how-to-change-text-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [JavaScript](http://www.echoecho.com/javascript.htm) so you can make changes to the [Document Object Model](http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/intro/default.asp)
It is very easy to learn and very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the javascript function document.getElementById (DIV THAT YOU WOULD LIKE TO PLACE IN).innerHTML = YOUR_TEXT;.

If you need a response from the server without reloading the page (you will still have to load, but the client will not notice), try using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You should use JavaScript to change the HTML used to display the page.

You will probably find it useful to use a library such as JQuery.