# JS value in html not showing properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a specific problem with JavaScript. When I print the value to console it shows everything ok. But in html it shows old value up until I choose another item than it refreshes the first item. Following is the js and html code:

**HTML**

```
onmouseover="OrderItem.setTotalPrice(event,this,'{{ menu_item.id }}')"
```

**JS**

```
setTotalPrice:function(event,a_htmlCaller, a_iMenuItemID){      

    item_total = OrderItem.Topping._order_toppings.find(function(a_oOTopp){
            return parseInt(a_oOTopp.iid) == parseInt(a_iMenuItemID);}.bind(this));

    var total_price = 0.00;
    var base_price = parseFloat($('pz-mitem-p-'+a_iMenuItemID).value);          
    var _html = '<div class="tot-price-item"><b>Item Price</b>: ';

    if(item_total){         
        // go into item details but with no changes     
        if(item_total.toppings.tot_price.length == 1 && item_total.toppings.tot_price[0].length == 0){                                      
            total_price += base_price;
            _html += '' + total_price;      
        }else{                          
            for(var i=0; i < item_total.toppings.tot_price.length; i++){

            //  total_price += parseFloat(item_total.toppings.tot_price[i][0]); 
                _html += '<div>' + (parseFloat(item_total.toppings.tot_price[i][0]).toFixed(2)).toString() + '</div>';          


            }               
        }       

    }else{          
        total_price += base_price;
        _html += '' + total_price;  
    }
    _html += '</div>';      



    Tips.add(
        a_htmlCaller, 
        event,                              
        _html,
        {
            className:'rounded',
            stem: true, 
            tipJoint: [ 'left', 'middle' ], 
            target:a_htmlCaller,    
            targetJoint: null//[ 'right', 'right' ]
        }
    );          

},
```

EDIT: Added code given by Asker in comment. Added formatting.

TIP: Instead of posting code in comments, post it as an edit in your original question, as it makes it much easier to read rather than a huge mess in a comment with absolutely no formatting.

```
for(var i=0; i < item_total.toppings.tot_price.length; i++) { 
    //total_price += parseFloat(item_total.toppings.tot_price[i][0]);
    _html += '<div>' + (parseFloat(item_total.toppings.tot_price[i][0]).toFixed(2)).toString() + '</div>';
    test = parseFloat(item_total.toppings.tot_price[i][0]).toFixed(2);
    console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code? Or even better, make a fiddle.

Comment: Where is the console.log that's working here? I can't see it. Are they in different places in the block?

Comment: 'for(var i=0; i < item_total.toppings.tot_price.length; i++){
          
    // total_price += parseFloat(item_total.toppings.tot_price[i][0]); 
     _html += '<div>' + (parseFloat(item_total.toppings.tot_price[i][0]).toFixed(2)).toString() + '</div>'; 
     
     test = parseFloat(item_total.toppings.tot_price[i][0]).toFixed(2);
     console.log(test);
           
    }'

Comment: we imported in our code the free tooltip from opentip.org

Answer (score 0):

It does not allow me to add a comment, so I am forced to post here.

Anyways, I suggest you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808348/change-html-code-without-refreshing-the-page)

Good luck to you!

(I would need more code in order to get a definite answer)