# execute a php function on ajax submit

Tags: php, ajax, forms

This is related to a site built on wordpress. I have a little system wherein some content from specific div `"content-div"` gets emailed to me via ajax submit. Please note that it does not use a `<form>` tag, as you will notice it in the codes below. Rest of the things are pretty straightforward.

**HTML** : Content is generated within the div and submit via `input-type=submit`.

```
<div id="content-div">
        //php generated content
</div>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT-CONTENT" id="button" onClick="handleFormSubmit()">
```

**AJAX** - Submit and redirect is done via this code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     function handleFormSubmit()
      {
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.style.display = 'none';
      }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
       {
         $('#button').click(function(){
         $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'http://awesomeness.com/pathto/processForm.php',
              data:{'message':$('#content-div').html(),'client': $('#some-field').val()           },
                  success:function(data) {
                  window.location = "http://awesomeness.com/thanks/";
             }
           });
          });
         });
    </script>
```

ProcessForm.php just contains basic html email codes. Here is what it looks like :

```
$to = "emailto@awesomepeople.com";
  $subject  = "NEW ARTICLE";
  $message .= $_POST['message'];
  $client   = $_POST ['client'];
  $headers = "From: awesomesite <someone@website.com>" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";           
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

All of this runs fine. Now there is another php function which needs to be run when the visitor hits the "SUBMIT-CONTENT" button. This function comes as a link.

```
<a class='wpfp-link' href='?wpfpaction=reset' rel='nofollow'>RESET</a>
```

Normally this link when clicked triggers a function which basically clears the browser cache and resets the main "content-div". Please note that I do not need this function's link on the page. I just need the functionality to somehow run on the submit. Basically when visitor clicks "SUBMIT-CONTENT", the function within the link should be executed as if the "RESET" link was clicked. This may happen on success submit and then the form must go with its usual routine eg. submit to processForm.php and redirect etc. I hope what I am asking is possible. If so how ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be some function that is parsing the querystring for `wpfpaction` key and `reset` value. I suggest finding that function and calling it before the `window.location`

Comment: Also, for those who can see deleted questions, this was asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556586/how-to-execute-a-php-function-on-ajax-submit

Comment: makes sense, i will look for the function, and I deleted as the solution were going nowhere,sorry though.

Comment: @andyb I found the function it triggers when clicked. It is `wpfp_reset_selected() {...}`. I have now clue how I would put it before the window.location, may be you can show me as an answer. I am sure this would work. thanks.

Comment: Assuming `wpfp_reset_selected` is a PHP function, you should be able to include that `.php` file where the function is defined in your  `ProcessForm.php` and call it call with `wpfp_reset_selected();` before the `ProcessForm.php` is finished.

Comment: I am having a tough time to execute your suggestion, can you please edit my code and show how this all should come together. thanks

Comment: I cannot edit code that is not in the question :) In your `ProcessForm.php` use [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) to add the `.php` file with `wpfp_reset_selected()` in, then after the `mail(...);` line write `wpfp_reset_selected();` to call the reset function.

Comment: thanks, working on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40011/discussion-between-gurung-and-andyb)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, at least not how you describe it.

When you do an Ajax request, you are sending parameters, then you can parse the response of the request.

Here I guess the output of the `wpfpaction=reset` will be HTML. One possibility is to replace the current HTML code of the page with the response from the ajax query to `wpfpaction=reset`.

See this question : [Change HTML code without refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808348/change-html-code-without-refreshing-the-page)